# How can I move shortcuts in a Web Part to a folder within that same Web Part?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have several Web Parts in a SP 2010 site, and each Web Part has a number of shortcut links, each with a URL and description. I have created a folder in the first Web Part to begin moving the links into it, but I cannot seem to find any option to do that, nor can I find any information about whether this is possible.

Am I missing some obvious feature/button somewhere? Or will I have to delete all these shortcuts and re-create them *inside* the folder?

The red arrow in the below image indicates the movement/change I'm looking to make:
[image]

Comment: One easy way is to use the "Open with Explorer" button in the ribbon (by the way, that webpart is usually refered to as a list view :) )

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks for the tip; I saw that elsewhere, but I don't have that option since this is a list. I will most likely have to re-create it as a Document Library. 

Even still, for Document Libraries, that feature is greyed out as a Site Owner, so I guess I'll have to ask to be made a super admin of my own site :-) ). It seems such a confounding thing for a software suite of such note in the marketplace to effectively bar you from moving files around easily. :-/

Comment: That it is greyed out can be caused by not using Internet Explorer. Files should be in document libraries as you mentions, since you have more functionality there, but I agree that folder handling is weak in SharePoint. You should try to use metadata on items and them create different view instead when possible

Comment: You might need to use content and structure or SharePoint designer to move them. Never used folders on a list, any reason not to add additional metadata to the list and just filter them away?

Comment: @PirateEric I hadn't yet thought to check with SharePoint Designer, thanks. Reason for putting them in folders was because the list will grow and grow and grow over time (typically per year[section] there are 10-20 links), so my supervisor wanted to avoid scrolling.

Comment: @RobertLindgren Oh, I forget that you need to use IE to "unlock" half of SharePoint's features. I will look again on IE. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: The power of good old ActiveX controls!